# MongoDB Aggregation in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to use collection.aggregate in NodeJS and is coming back with a blank error.

This is what I have so far, which works in terminal directly with MongoDB

```
const something = await Collection.aggregate([{ '$match': { 'clientId': 80 }}]);

res.send(something)
```

I have tried this in the past and it did work and nothing has changed (my code file is probably 5 lines at this point)

Comment: Again what is the type of the `clientId` in your schema? Could you show some sample documents as well

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet The type is Int. I can't share any docs at the moment

Comment: Probably you are checking the wrong database.

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet nope I am 100% on that :) Node js comes back with an empty error so something goes wrong here...